# Invert orientation of memory space?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I'm trying to read some bytes from a file.

This is what I've done:

```
struct HeaderData {
    char format[2];
    char n_trks[2];
    char division[2];
};

HeaderData* header = new HeaderData;
```

Then, to get the data directly from the file to `header` I do

```
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(header), sizeof(HeaderData))
```

If the first two bytes are`00 06`, `header->format[0]` will be `00` and `header->format[1]` `06`. This two numbers combined represent the number `0x0006` which is `6` in decimal, which is the desired value.

When I do something like

```
*reinterpret_cast<unsigned*>(header->format) // In this case, the result is 0x0600
```

it erroneously returns the number `0x0600`, so it seems that it **inverts** the reading of bytes.

My question is what is some workaround to correctly read the numbers as unsigned.

Comment: Are you relying on the (probably wrong) architecture concerning big endian vs. little endian form of storing integers?

Comment: `*reinterpret_cast<unsigned*>(header->format)` is undefined behaviour anyway. You should use `unsigned char` in your structure and then the 16-bit integer value is `format[0] * 256 + format[1];`.

Comment: I think it is well-defined behaviour, since char* and unsigned* may legally alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be an endianness mismatch.

When you read in from the file in that fashion, the bytes will be placed into your structure in the exact order they were in the file in.

When you read from the structure with an `unsigned`, the processor will interpret those bytes in whatever order the architecture requires it to do (most are hardcoded but some can be set to either order).

Or to put it another way

> This two numbers combined represent the number 0x0006 which is 6 in decimal.

That's not necessarily remotely true. It's perfectly permissible for the processor of your choice to represent 6 in decimal as 0x06 0x00, this would be the little-endian scheme which is used on very common processors like x86. Representing it as 0x00 0x06 would be big-endian.

As M.M has stated in his comment, if your format explicitly defines the integer to be little-endian, you should explicitly read it as little-endian, e.g. `format[0] + format[1] * 256`, or if it is defined to be big-endian, you should read it as `format[0] * 256 + format[1]`. Don't rely on the processor's endianness happening to match the endianness of the data.

Comment: I knew that 0x0006 is 6 in that context, I forgot to add to it, I've edited it.

Comment: You obviously don't know any such thing, since your processor seems to think that 0x00 0x06 is 0x600.

Comment: I read on the docs of midi and at the start it puts what defines a header, there there are some bytes and following that a 00 06 byte sequence which represents 6, so I knew that beforehand; reading byte by byte gives me the correct answers. What I didn't knew is the endiannes of my computer.

Comment: That defines the endianness of your data format, not the endianness of how your processor will interpret the data in your memory space.